# Scientific Notation Conversion (meters to yards)

Tags: unit-of-measure

Carry out the following conversion. Express your answer in scientific notation. (must show your work to earn credit)

12.56 x 10^-2 m to yards (helpful hint: 1 inch= 2.54cm; 1 foot= 12 inches; 3 feet= 1 yard)

Comment: might have been easier to go find the internationally accepted conversion of a yard into metres

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee well it's not that hard to multiply $2.54\times 36$...

Comment: @zwim I am required to show my work to get it correct and I do not understand how to conclude to the answer. Where did you get 36?

Comment: @Vaios Vlahotasios: 36 inches is 1 yard

Comment: @Vasya why do I need that? I am very confused. Can you show me the solution?

Comment: If we do the work, then shouldn't we get the credit (and not you)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$1m=100cm=\large{\frac {100}{2.54 \cdot 36}}yd$ (if 1 inch is 2.54 cm then to find number of inches in 100 cm we need to divide 100 by 2.54)

Thus: $12.56 \cdot 10^{-2} m=\large{\frac {12.56}{2.54 \cdot 36}}yd$